# Check if the key already exists (RegOpenKey)

Tags: c++, winapi, registry

I did this:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    HKEY CH;

    if(RegCreateKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run",&CH) != 0)
    {
        printf("Erro - RegCreateKey\n");
        system("PAUSE");
        return -1;
   }
    if(RegOpenKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run",&CH) != 0) // Abre a CH "Minha CH"
    {
        printf("Erro - RegOpenKey\n");
        system("PAUSE");
        return -1;
    }
    if(RegSetValueEx(CH,L"PROC",0,REG_SZ,(LPBYTE) L"C:\\pasta1\\pasta2\\txt.txt",200) != 0)
        printf("Erro - RegSetValue\n");
    RegCloseKey(CH);
    printf("\nsucesso !\n");
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
     system("PAUSE");
}
```

Now I want do it:

```
 if(key already exist) {
            //don't make nothing 
} else
     Create key
      ...
```

What the function that I need to do it ?  Because if not, I ever gonna create a key that already exist. And if I can avoid it would be great.

Comment: Just call `RegCreateKeyEx`. It opens the key if it already exists, and creates it if it doesn't. Problem solved?

Comment: But and the RegSetValueEx ? It gonna do same thing that RegCreateKey ?

Comment: `RegSetValueEx` would create a new value if it doesn't exist, or overwrite existing value.

Comment: Ok, if it does not harm, So. . . problem solved. . .

Answer (score 2):

Use `RegCreateKeyEx`. It opens the key if it already exists, and creates it if it doesn't. `lpdwDisposition` parameter tells you which of these two effects actually happened.  For example:

```
DWORD disposition = 0;
RegCreateKeyEx(..., &disposition);
if (disposition == REG_CREATED_NEW_KEY) {
    /* new key was created */
} else {
    /* existing key was opened */
}
```

Comment: `DWORD disposition = 0; RegCreateKeyEx(..., &disposition); if (disposition == REG_CREATED_NEW_KEY) { /* new key was created */ } else { /* existing key was opened */ }` Error checking is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: So what is the point of using RegOpenKeyEx(...)?   Wouldn't only using RegCreateKeyEx(...) save the need to write extra validation code?

Comment: @funa68: You would use `RegOpenKeyEx` when you want to open an existing key, but do not want to create a new one if it doesn't exist.